# Installing Chromium OS on USB throws error

Tags: usb-flash-drive, google-chrome-os

I'm trying to install Chromium OS on my netbook via USB. I have the USB, went into Disk Utility, clicked erase. And it erased all data. Format is Fat 32.

However, when I run the Chromium OS Image Creator, and try using the USB, it throws this error:

"Sorry, an error occurred (failed to open the USB stick, Permission denied). Would you like to try again?"

What can I do to fix this?

OS X 10.8.2 Mountain Lion.

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: @MarcusChan, Kind of. I just decided to write to the USB from Windows instead. I read somewhere that the Mac version does not actually work, but if anyone knows how to get it to work, I would love to know how.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run this in the Terminal with the Image Creator app in applications:

```
sudo "/Applications/Chromium OS Image Creator.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium OS Image Creator"
```

This runs the 'Chromium OS Image Creator.app' with the correct permissions. Some tips:

1. Make sure the app is in the Applications folder.
2. Make sure the app is not running.
3. Run the command in the Terminal app.
4. Enter your password in Terminal if `sudo` asks for it.
5. Make sure the target device (e.g. USB drive) is somewhere other than the root hard drive.
6. Continue to use the app as normal.